# Parse push json IOS webview

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, webview

I have an ios webview app and I am trying to push links to articles. I for the life of me can't figure out how to do it. Each notification just opens the home page. Any help out there?  I am 100% new at this so if you can please explain it to me like the idiot I am.

## import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

/// The interstitial ad.

@end

@implementation ViewController {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  if ([useragent  isEqual: @""]) { } else {
      NSDictionary *customuseragent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:useragent, @"UserAgent", nil];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:customuseragent];
  }

  // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;

  CGRect phonecheck = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  double statusbar = 20;
  double height = phonecheck.size.height = phonecheck.size.height-statusbar;
  _webView.frame= CGRectMake(0, 20, phonecheck.size.width, height);
  _loadingSign.center = CGPointMake((phonecheck.size.width/2), (phonecheck.size.height/2));

  if (phonecheck.size.height == 667-statusbar) {
      _offline.frame= CGRectMake(103,228,170,170);
      _text1.frame= CGRectMake(40,400,295,50);
      _text2.frame= CGRectMake(25,435,326,50);
      _tryButton.frame= CGRectMake(110,520,150,20);
  }
  if (phonecheck.size.height == 736-statusbar) {
      _offline.frame= CGRectMake(123,205,170,170);
      _text1.frame= CGRectMake(60,346,295,50);
      _text2.frame= CGRectMake(44,374,326,50);
      _tryButton.frame= CGRectMake(132,453,150,20);
  }
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
  NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:webviewurl];
  _webView.delegate = self;
  if ([preventoverscroll  isEqual: @"true"]) {
      _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
  }
  if ([deletechache  isEqual: @"true"]) {
      [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
  }
  _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  [_webView.scrollView setBouncesZoom:NO];
  [_webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
  _offline.hidden = true;
  [_loadingSign stopAnimating];
  _loadingSign.hidden = true;
  [_tryButton setTitle:buttontext forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [_tryButton setTitle:buttontext forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  _text1.text = screen1;
  _text2.text = screen2;
  _text1.hidden = true;
  _text2.hidden = true;
  _tryButton.hidden = true;
  NSString *onlinecheck = [url absoluteString];
  if ([uselocalhtmlfolder  isEqual: @"true"]) {
      NSURL *urllocal = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]];
      [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urllocal]];
  } else{
      if ([onlinecheck length] == 0){
          _offline.hidden = false;
          _webView.hidden = true;
          _text1.hidden = false;
          _text2.hidden = false;
          _tryButton.hidden = false;
          _loadingSign.hidden = true;
      }
      else {
          NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  ```
      [_webView loadRequest:request];
  }
  ```

  }
  NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  srand(time(NULL));
  int randnum = arc4random()%10;
  if ([user boolForKey:@"ratemyapp"] == 0) {
      { if (randnum==1){
          [user setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"ratemyapp"];
          [user synchronize];
          [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:ratemyapptitle
                                  message: ratemyapptext
                        cancelButtonTitle:ratemyappno
                        otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:ratemyappyes, nil]
                                onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex)
           {
               NSString *prefeedback = [NSString stringWithFormat:ratemyappurl];
               NSURL *feedback = [NSURL URLWithString:prefeedback];
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:feedback];
           }
                                 onCancel:^()
           {
           }
           ];
      }}}
  if ([user boolForKey:@"becomefbfriends"] == 0) {
      { if (randnum==2){
          [user setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"becomefbfriends"];
          [user synchronize];
          [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:becomefacebookfriendstitle
                                  message: becomefacebookfriendstext
                        cancelButtonTitle:becomefacebookfriendsno
                        otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:becomefacebookfriendsyes, nil]
                                onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex)
           {
               NSString *prefeedback = [NSString stringWithFormat:becomefacebookfriendsurl];
               NSURL *feedback = [NSURL URLWithString:prefeedback];
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:feedback];
           }
                                 onCancel:^()
           {
           }
           ];
      }}}
  if ([user boolForKey:@"firstrun"] == 0) {{
      UIAlertView *showfirstrunmessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: firstrunmessagetitle message: firstrunmessage delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: okbutton otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [user setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"firstrun"];
      [user synchronize];
      [showfirstrunmessage show];
  }}

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
- (IBAction)tryagain:(id)sender {
  NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:webviewurl];
  NSString *onlinecheckagain = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
  if ([onlinecheckagain length] == 0) {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: offlinetitle message: offlinemsg delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: okbutton otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [alert show];
  }
  else {
      _offline.hidden = true;
      _text1.hidden = true;
      _text2.hidden = true;
      _tryButton.hidden = true;
      _webView.hidden = false;
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [_webView loadRequest:request];
  }

}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  [_loadingSign startAnimating];
  _loadingSign.hidden = false;

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_loadingSign stopAnimating];
    _loadingSign.hidden = true;
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:webviewurl];

```
NSString *onlinecheckagain = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ([onlinecheckagain length] == 0) {
    webView.hidden = true;
    _loadingSign.hidden = true;
    _offline.hidden = false;
    _text1.hidden = false;
    _text2.hidden = false;
    _tryButton.hidden = false;
}}
```

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];
    if ([[requestURL host] isEqualToString:@"push.send.cancel"]) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; return NO;}
    if ([[requestURL host] isEqualToString:@"push.send"]) {
        NSURL *prerequest = requestURL;
        NSString *finished = [prerequest absoluteString];
        NSArray *requested = [finished componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
        NSString *seconds = [requested objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSArray *logindetails = [finished componentsSeparatedByString: @"msg!"];
        NSString *logindetected = [logindetails objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSArray *logindetailsmore = [logindetected componentsSeparatedByString: @"&!#"];
        NSString *msg0 = [logindetailsmore objectAtIndex: 0];
        NSString *button0 = [logindetailsmore objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSString *msg = [msg0 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
        NSString *button = [button0 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
        double sendafterseconds = [seconds doubleValue];
        UILocalNotification *pushmsg1 =     [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        pushmsg1.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:sendafterseconds];
        pushmsg1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        pushmsg1.alertBody = msg;
        pushmsg1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        pushmsg1.alertAction = button;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]     scheduleLocalNotification:pushmsg1];
        return NO;
    }
    if ([uselocalhtmlfolder  isEqual: @"true"]) {
        if ( ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ] || [ [ requestURL scheme ]isEqualToString: @"mailto" ]) && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
            return NO;
        }else{
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ([openallexternalurlsinsafaribydefault  isEqual: @"true"]) {
            NSString *predefaulthost = [webviewurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
            NSString *defaulthost = [predefaulthost stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"https://" withString:@""];
            if ([[requestURL host] isEqualToString:defaulthost]) { }else{[_loadingSign stopAnimating];
                _loadingSign.hidden = true;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                return NO;}}

```
    /* Open specific URL "http://maps.google.com" links in Safari START */
    if ([[requestURL host] isEqualToString:@"maps.google.com"]) /* WITHOUT HTTP/HTTPS */{
        [_loadingSign stopAnimating];
        _loadingSign.hidden = true;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
        return NO;
    } /* Open specific URL "http://maps.google.com" links in Safari END */



    return YES;
}
```

}
@end

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: see this http://pastebin.com/q2BvTwS6 it's my view controler.m

Comment: Post the relevant piece of code on SO, don't link to it. Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am so new I don't know what I am doing. I literally got a book last week.

Comment: I think I posted it. Trying to push a specific link so when the user gets a notification it opens a specific page on our site.